# For each value, find the smallest distance within the group using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

suppose I have the following data frame df

```
group value
a       1
a       0
a       3
b       1
b       4
```

For each value, I want to find the closest value in the same group ('a' or 'b')，and then output the difference between the value and the closest value to it.

The output should look like this:

```
group value min_diff
a       1    1
a       0    1
a       3    2
b       1    3
b       4    3
```

`

Thank you!

Comment: you say closest value in same group? so that means for the first entry, a is the group, 1 is the value, the closes value to 1, that is in a is 0 is it not? How is it 1?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I want the output to be the smallest difference after identifying the closest value. Already made the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-[`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
tmp = df.sort_values('value')

out = (pd.merge_asof(
           tmp.reset_index(),
           tmp.rename(columns={'value': 'value_'}),
           by='group',
           left_on='value', right_on='value_',
           direction='nearest',
           allow_exact_matches=False)
         .assign(min_diff=lambda d: d['value'].sub(d.pop('value_')).abs())
         .set_index('index').reindex(df.index)
       )
```

If you can have duplicated values within a group (see example below) and would like to report `0` in this case, you further need to process the output:

```
out.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['group', 'value'], keep=False), 'min_diff'] = 0
```

Output:

```
  group  value  min_diff
0     a      1         1
1     a      0         1
2     a      3         2
3     b      1         3
4     b      4         3
```

Intermediate after the `merge_asof`:

```
   index group  value  value_
0      1     a      0       1
1      0     a      1       0
2      3     b      1       4
3      2     a      3       1
4      4     b      4       1
```

---

##### handling duplicated values

Because of `allow_exact_matches=False`, matching the same value is prevented.

Without correction:

```
  group  value  min_diff
0     a      1         1
1     a      0         1
2     a      3         2
3     b      1         3
4     b      4         3
5     c      8         1
6     c      9         1  # matched with 8
7     c      9         1  #
```

After correction with `out.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['group', 'value'], keep=False), 'min_diff'] = 0`:

```
  group  value  min_diff
0     a      1         1
1     a      0         1
2     a      3         2
3     b      1         3
4     b      4         3
5     c      8         1
6     c      9         0  # matched with each other
7     c      9         0  #
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the min absolute difference between every vaule and all of the other values in the same group with the help of groupby function

The code will be if you want to merge into original df:

```
df['min_diff'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.sub(x.iloc[0]).abs().min())
```

if you just want the output: `df['min_diff'] = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]`

You will have to use lists;

```
min_diff_list = []

# Iterate through each row in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    group = row['group']
    value = row['value']
    
    # Filter the DataFrame to get values in the same group
    group_values = df[df['group'] == group]['value']
    
    # Calculate the minimum absolute difference
    min_diff = (group_values - value).abs().min()
    
    # Append the minimum difference to the list
    min_diff_list.append(min_diff)

# Create a new 'min_diff' column in the original DataFrame
df['min_diff'] = min_diff_list

# Print the DataFrame
print(df['min_diff'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with numpy broadcasting:

```
def closest(s):
    a = (s.to_numpy()[:,None] - s.to_numpy()).astype(float)
    a[np.where(np.eye(s.size))] = np.NaN
    return np.nanmin(np.abs(a),axis=1).tolist()

df.join(df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(closest).rename('min_diff'))
```

Output:

```
  group  value  min_diff
0     a      1       1.0
1     a      0       1.0
2     a      3       2.0
3     b      1       3.0
4     b      4       3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'value': [1, 0, 3, 1, 4]})
"""print(df)
  group  value
0     a      1
1     a      0
2     a      3
3     b      1
4     b      4"""


def f(group, value):
    group_values = df[df['group'] == group]['value'].to_numpy()
    #print('group_values : ',group_values)
    #print("....")
    value_arr = np.repeat(value, len(group_values))
    #print('value_arr :',value_arr)
    #print("....")
    diff = np.abs(group_values[:, None] - value_arr)
    #print('diff :',diff)
    #print("....")
    mask = (group_values != value)
    closest_diff = np.min(diff[mask])
    #print('closest_diff : ', closest_diff)
    return closest_diff



df['min_diff']  = df.apply(lambda row: f( row['group'], row['value']),axis=1 )
"""print(df)
  group  value  min_diff
0     a      1         1
1     a      0         1
2     a      3         2
3     b      1         3
4     b      4         3"""
```